# Error deploying SharePoint 2010 solution with InfoPath form (The path is not of a legal form.)

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am new to SharePoint and .Net development, sorry if answer for my question is obvious.

I've created SharePoint solution, which uses InfoPath form. When I deploy it from Visual Studio, all work fine, but when I try to deploy WSP package from web interface it fails with error:

```
[ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.]
System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck) +3806
System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path) +245       
Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver.EnumerateFormTemplates(SPFeatureDefinition featureDef) +156
Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver.FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) +789
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.DoInstallationCallout(SPSite site, String solutionHash, Boolean fInstall) +27309665
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.Install(SPSite site, String solutionHash) +444
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinitionCollection.AddCore(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, SPSite site, String solutionHash, Boolean fForce, Boolean fDoValidation) +26381365
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinitionCollection.AddInternal(String relativePathToFeatureManifest, Guid solutionId, String solutionHash, SPSite site, Boolean force, Boolean fDoValidation, SPFeatureDefinitionContext featureDefinitionContext) +174
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.AddFeatureDefinitions(SPFeatureDefinitionCollection featColl, SPFeatureDefinitionContext context, Boolean force, Boolean activateFeatures, SPSite site, SPWeb web) +290
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUserCodeSolutionPackage.EnableSiteCollectionSolution(SPSite site, Int32 solutionGalleryItemId, Boolean force) +23867323
Microsoft.SharePoint.<>c__DisplayClass1.<AddOrUpgrade>b__0() +4075
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +27948246
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.AddOrUpgrade(SPListItem item, SPUserSolution existingSolution) +449
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.Add(Int32 solutionGalleryItemId) +574
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SolutionItemButton.ActivateItem() +398
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPLinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +72
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

My module Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Forms">
    <File Path="Forms\CustomTaskForm1.xsn" Url="Forms/CustomTaskForm1.xsn" />
    <File Path="Forms\CustomTaskForm0.xsn" Url="Forms/CustomTaskForm0.xsn" />
    <File Path="Forms\CustomTaskForm7.xsn" Url="Forms/CustomTaskForm7.xsn" />
    <File Path="Forms\ApproveTaskForm.xsn" Url="Forms/ApproveTaskForm.xsn" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

There is an answer to the problem [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sharepoint2010customization/thread/d648be5c-8613-494f-a7f0-9f7763710411), which tells that the error occurs then Path attrubute is incorrect, but I can't understand what directory is current and how I have to change the Path attribute. Could you help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Now it works. It seems like the root of the problem is [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680544/cant-find-workflow-deployed-as-wsp-solution-when-i-deploy-it-from-vs-it-works/9682862#9682862):
I've tryed to add WSP Farm solution to sandbox solution gallery. I have to use another way for deploying, for example PowerShell.

PS: Thanks to [Balamurugan-S KAUST answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f73236e8-98e7-4a4d-a9cb-c543ab59aca9)