# Can't find workflow deployed as WSP solution (when I deploy it from VS it works)

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp

I am new to SharePoint, sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

I am trying to deploy my very simple workflow as WSP package, it deploys without errors, I activate it, but I can't find my workflow and associate it with list. Could you help me, please, what I do wrong?

I do it so:

1. Create empty project[image: Create empty project]
2. Choose trust level as a Farm solution[image]
3. Add State Machine Workflow[image]
4. Choose list Workflow[image]
5. Associate workflow with list Task[image]
   [image]
6. Create simple workflow
   [image]
7. Press CTRL-F5 in VS2010, and see that WF appears
   [image]
   [image]
8. Pack it to WSP package
   [image]
9. Upload and activate it.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
10. Check is it associated to list. It doesn't.
    [image]
11. Try to associate it manually, but I can't see it. Why? Where is my error?
    [image]
    [image]

I try to google about the problem, but find nothing.
I think that I missed something important in basic priciples, but I can't understand what. Help me please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. The root of the problem is next:
I've tryed to add WSP Farm solution to sandbox solution gallery. I have to use another way for deploying, for example PowerShell.

PS: Thanks to [Balamurugan-S KAUST answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f73236e8-98e7-4a4d-a9cb-c543ab59aca9)